# Consuming .Net web service from PHP - how to debug

Tags: .net, php, web-services

I'm using PHP5 integrated SOAP Client. My web service method accepts around 30 parameters from string and int to bool and double. Upon calling the method I get the following error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Server was unable to read request.
>
> ---> There is an error in XML document (3, 983).
>
> ---> Input string was not in a correct format.

How can I get to this XML document to check what this error is about? Do I do this on PHP side or on .Net side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SOAP Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972353.aspx) to log the XML on the server side.

If you save the SOAP message to a file and open it in Internet Explorer (or your favorite XML editor), you should see the error.